# Ошибка в массиве с объектом

Tags: php

```
$payload = [
  "stocks": [
    {
      "offer_id": "826566",
      "product_id": 0,
      "stock": 3
    }
  ]
]
```

Подскажите как это поправить чтоб не было синтаксической ошибки ?

Comment: Кавычки забыл. и ещё по мелочи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы так хотели?

```
$payload = [
  "stocks" => [
    (object)[
      "offer_id"   =>  "826566",
      "product_id" =>  0,
      "stock"      =>  3
    ]
  ]
];

echo $payload['stocks'][0]->offer_id;
```

Или так

```
$payload = [
  "stocks" => [
    '[{
       "offer_id"   :  "826566",
       "product_id" :  0,
       "stock"      :  3
    }]'
  ]
];
//но в таком случае нужен json_decode
echo json_decode($payload['stocks'][0])[0]->offer_id;
```

Comment: проще кавычки добавить и синтакс поправить чтобы нормальный джейсон получился

Comment: @Ипатьев а я вообще не пойму зачем этот цирк... Но "Ошибка в массиве с объектом" не вижу тут ничего про json